# Yii RESTFul with JSON format Update and Create

Tags: mysql, json, http, rest, yii

I am trying to implement RESTFul in Yii framework with JSON formatting. I have a single user table as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    id int(10) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    nickname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

And in my Yii `userController.php` class (my yii application has CRUD implemented with gii).
I have the following two functions that basically handle the CRUD APIs using RESTful and JSON formatting as shown below:

```
public function actionRead($id=''){
    $requestType = Yii::app()->request->getRequestType();
    if($requestType !== 'GET' && $id === ''){
        throw new Exception('$id must be specified or acces this service with GET!');
        return;
    }

    if($id !== '0'){
        $user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1');
        $user->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $user = $user->queryRow();
    }else{
        $user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM user WHERE 1');
        $user = $user->queryAll();
    }

    echo json_encode($user);

}


public function actionSave($id){
    $requestType = Yii::app()->request->getRequestType();
    if($requestType !== 'POST'){
        throw new Exception('Acces this service with POST!');
        return;
    }

    $post = Yii::app()->request->getPost('form');

    if($id !== ''){//update...need help with logic here for update

    }else{//create...need help with logic here for create

    }

    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO user (id, email) VALUES (null, :email)');
    $command->bindParam(':email', $post['email']);


    return json_encode($command->execute());
}
```

With the code above, I am able to view and list the data using a client in Google Chrome. But I am having trouble with the getting the update and create working. I have put place holders for the two implementations of `"create"` and `"update"` in the code above in comments.

Can I get some ideas or solutions on how I can achieve this.

Comment: what do you want update?

Comment: Do you have a User model?

Comment: Alex, i want to be able to update the email, nickname and password from the provided table. Darkhier, yes i do have the user model. I am using the Google chrome rest client to test the code above and the actionRead() function works just fine when tested using the following RESTful client:chrome-extension://fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have User model, then your code will look like:

```
$post = Yii::app()->request->getPost('form');

if($id !== ''){//update...need help with logic here for update
     $model = User::model()->findByPk($id);
}else{//create...need help with logic here for create
     $model = new User;
}
$model->email = $post['email'];
$model->nickname = $post['nickname'];
$model->password = $post['password'];
$model->save();

return json_encode($model->id);
```

If $post has array of attributes.